# PyPlot: How to change the xlabel background color and that the xlabel is above the plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, julia

[image: How to give the xlabel background a yellow color with alpha]

How do I give the xlabel background a yellow color? When I use bbox, the xlabel is behind the plot. How to bring it to the front? I tried my hand at adjusting the zorder, but couldn't set zorder for the axis label.

Python or Julia code will be helpful.

This is the code I'm currently using:

```
fig=figure(4)
ax = gca()

xlabel("Rotor position [mm]", horizontalalignment="right", x=1.0, color="gray", bbox=Dict("facecolor"=>"yellow","edgecolor"=>"None"))
ylabel("Force [N]",fontdict=font1, horizontalalignment="right", y=1.0, fontdict=font1, color="gray")
ax[:invert_xaxis]()

plot(x_rotor,Fx_net_off,"--",label=L"F$_{\rm total}: 0\ \rm AT$")
plot(x_rotor,Fx_net_pos,label=L"F$_{\rm total}: +100\ \rm AT$")
plot(x_rotor,Fx_net_neg,label=L"F$_{\rm total}: -100\ \rm AT$")
font1 = Dict("color"=>"k")

ax[:spines]["top"][:set_visible](false) # Hide the top edge of the axis
ax[:spines]["right"][:set_visible](false) # Hide the right edge of the axis
ax[:spines]["left"][:set_position]("center") # Move the right axis to the center
ax[:spines]["bottom"][:set_position]("center") # Most the bottom axis to the center
ax[:xaxis][:set_ticks_position]("bottom") # Set the x-ticks to only the bottom
ax[:yaxis][:set_ticks_position]("left") # Set the y-ticks to only the left

ax[:spines]["left"][:set_color]("gray")
ax[:tick_params](axis="y", colors="gray")

ax[:spines]["bottom"][:set_color]("gray")
ax[:tick_params](axis="x", colors="gray")

PyPlot.xticks([x_rotor[1],0.1,0,-0.1,x_rotor[end]])

xlim([0.2,-0.2])

fig[:canvas][:draw]() # Update the figure
```

Comment: Sorry a white color with alpha? Isn't that just transparent.

Comment: You will change the backgroundcolor just as you currently do, just use some other color than white to see the effect, e.g. `backgroundcolor = "red"`.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest - I would like the label to be displayed clearly. Currently, it gets hidden by the plot. I tried changing the color and as you can see, the plot seems to come over the xlabel bbox and hence changing alpha doesn't help with hiding these lines.

Comment: I solved it by giving a negative zorder value for the blue dashed plot and it works now. I can't add the picture again to show. But it works. Thank you @ImportanceOfBeingErnest